# ")" is not valid at this position, expecting an identifier CREATE TABLE

Tags: mysql, create-table

I'm keep getting this error ")"  is not valid at this position, expecting an identifier
although I had created table similar way but getting this error for any new table I'm trying to create.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS company.employee(
    fname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    mname CHAR NULL,
    laname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    ssn CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    Bdate DATE,
    Adress VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
    Sex CHAR NULL,
    Salary DECIMAL (10,2) NULL,
    Supper_ssn CHAR(9) NULL,
    Dno INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ssn)
    );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS company.Department(
    Dname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Dnumber INT NOT NULL,
    Mgr_ssn CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    Mgr_start_date DATE NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Dnumber)
    );

USE compnay;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS projects(

    Pname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Pnumber INT NOT NULL,
    Plocation VARCHAR(15),
    Dnum INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Pnumber),
    UNIQUE(Pname)
    );    

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Dept_location(
    Dnumber INT NOT NULL,
    Dlocation VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Dnumber,Dlocation)
    );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Works_on(
Essn CHAR(9) NOT NULL,[![enter image description here][1]][1]

);
```

Comment: You can't put comma sign at the end of the last line, so you should remove it from this line Essn CHAR(9) NOT NULL,

Comment: the error complains about the `)`, you must always look at the stuff right before the character (or text) , so (in this case) remove the `,`

Comment: @shobe  and luuk thanks... I remove the ',' and it works now. that was silly mistake from my side...

Answer (score 0):

in the line 41 try removing the "," .